# Explanation for various solutions to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

**Disclaimer**: I translated this from German, so I might be using some of the mathematical terms incorrectly. Please don't hesitate to tell me if this is the case, so I can fix it.

Could someone please explain the following problem and its solution in simple terms? This is a problem from my textbook concerning a system of linear equations from my textbook where $$ A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 2 & 1\end{array}\right)\in M_{34}(\mathbb{R})$$
and where 'U' is the set of all solutions for Ax = 0 and 'L' is the set of all solutions for $$Ax = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$$

Am I right in assuming that this means the following?: $$ L = \left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$$
and $$ U = \left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

Of the solutions a-d, a and b are true, according to my book, but since it doesn't really offer any additional explanation, I Just can't figure out why this is the case. I would be very grateful to anyone who can explain this to me.

(a) 
$$L = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)+U$$

(b) 
$$L = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1/2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)+U$$

(c) 
$$L = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)+U$$

(d) 
$$L = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{array}\right)+U$$

Comment: For $x \in \mathbb R^4$ we have that $Ax \in \mathbb R^3$. Since $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) \in \mathbb R^4$, the equation $Ax = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$ is nonsense.

Comment: yes you will get a 3 element vector if you multiply with the matrix from the left on a 4 element vector.

Comment: It's not a matrix multiplication, but a system of linear equations. I hope the edits I made make it a little clearer.

Comment: Your notation is a bit strange but it makes more sense now.

Comment: To verify that a vector solves it, you can do scalar product with each row and the result should be the right hand side.